# java maven missing plugin descriptor for plexus-utils

Tags: java, maven, plugins, descriptor

I know I am a Java newbie, but I need to build several Ubuntu packages on launchpad. I fixed a lot of dependency problems but am now stuck with the following error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] FATAL ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] The plugin descriptor for the plugin Plugin [org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils] was not found. Please verify that the plugin JAR [removed]/maven-repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.5/plexus-utils-3.0.5.jar is intact.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[DEBUG] Trace
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The plugin descriptor for the plugin Plugin [org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils] was not found. 
Please verify that the plugin JAR [removed]/maven-repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.5/plexus-utils-3.0.5.jar is intact.
```

The jar is downloaed and available. So what is going wrong and how to fix it?

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Jeroen

Comment: Is there a `plexus-utils-3.0.5.pom` file in the same directory as the jar?

Comment: Are you behind corporate firewall/proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out plexus-utils is not a plugin but a regular dependency. That fixed it for me.